# parse date string in JavaScript to get timezone offset

Tags: javascript, jquery, timezone

I have date string like `Fri, 15 Nov 2013 09:00:00 -0600` in JavaScript(sent by server PHP). I need to parse this and get the timezone offset '-0600'. 
Is there any easy way to get the timezone offset from this string?

Thanks

Comment: Do you have access to the PHP, it might be cleaner to do this on the server side. Not to mention PHP's time/date functions are a little more flexible IMO.

Comment: Have you tried using [`Date.parse()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse) in conjunction with [`Date.getTimezoneOffset()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTimezoneOffset)?

Comment: @DCoder getTimezoneOffset() returns the local offset on the specified date, not the offset from the string.

Comment: @DavidHoude I have access to PHP, but I think I dont want get timezone offset of each event time and send to clinet seperately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var str = "Fri, 15 Nov 2013 09:00:00 -0600"
var output = str.split(' ').pop();
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/D7c28/

Comment: split didnt work directly in some cases, I am using like 'str.toString().split(' ').pop()'. Yet to test on all browsers.

Answer (score 0):

```
var reg_exp = /(-|\+)\d{4}/,
    timezone_offset = reg_exp.match("Fri, 15 Nov 2013 09:00:00 -0600")[0];
```